# finding variances for powers of a gaussian’s random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I’ve been given a gaussian distribution
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = Ce^{-x^2 -y^2 +xy}$$ and was asked to find the biggest variance out of several expressions. I started by finding the matrix $A$ and inverting it to get $\Sigma$.
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = Ce^{-\tfrac{1}{2}(2x^2+2y^2-2xy)} \implies A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \implies \Sigma = \frac{1}{3} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then I was able to find $\textsf{Var}(X+Y)$ and $\textsf{Var}(X-Y)$ mostly by using covariances and the matrix, but I hit a snag trying to find $\textsf{Var}(\frac{1}{2} Y^3)$ and $\textsf{Var}(X^2)$. I seem to recall there’s more than one method of finding it, but I really don’t know it.

Comment: I Found a previous exam’s solution. They seem to define a new random variable U - can you explain what is happening there to me please? https://imgur.com/a/EswzZPR

Comment: I understand the trick and will post a solution if able

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the matrix square root of $\Sigma$ to express X,Y linearly in terms of two independent standard Gaussians.

Indeed if $S$ is symmetric such that $S^2 = \Sigma$, then for $U,V$ is an independent pair of standard Gaussians, $(X,Y) = S(U,V)$ is a Gaussian of covariance $\Sigma$.

Then it's easy to do all the computations you want.

Answer (score 1):

alright so the trick is to define a new canonized random variable $Z \sim \textsf{N_[0,1]}$ as an expression of your own random variable.

 for instance I want $\textsf{Var}(0.5Y^3)$: $$ Z := \frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma} = \frac{Y-0}{\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}}$$ (we find mean by equating divergence to 0). 
and I know how to find Z’s expectations and variances.
$$\textsf{Var}(0.5Y^3) = \textsf{Var}(0.5(\sqrt{2/3}Z)^3)$$ and this is much more doable.